# Is it Possible to Render a Web Page Whilst Closing a Web Socket?

Tags: javascript, perl, websocket, mojolicious

I am opening a web socket connection to my server to generate some data. I display this data in a *simulated* terminal window on my web page. I would also like to show this data in a table on a new blank page.

I'm using Mojolicious and Template Toolkit, and I'd like to take advantage of TT2 to generate this report. I'd prefer not to generate the table using javascript.

Is it possible to render a new page as I close the web socket in Mojolicious?

```
# all done, send report data to javascript and close web socket
$c->on(finish => sub {
    my ($c, $code, $reason) = @_;
    $c->send({
        json => {
            command             => $cmd,
            cli_flag            => $cli_flag,
            cli_errstr          => $cli_errstr,
            coord_bc            => \%coord_bc,
            coord               => \%coord,
        },
    });
    Mojo::IOLoop->remove($id);
    $c->app->log->debug("WebSocket closed with status $code");
});
```

In other words, can I put:

```
$c->stash(\%vars);
$c->render(template => $template);
```

inside the `finish` event handler? I suspect this isn't possible.

The only way I can think of to do this is to (1) generate the table in javascript or (2) redirect program flow back to a new get route in Mojolicious to have it render the page using TT2.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks.